# How to access Properties or Methods using Strings?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created Custom font Icons using fluttericon.com which looks like this:

```
// fa_pro_light_icons.dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class FaProLight {
  FaProLight._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'FaProLight';

  static const IconData cash_register = const IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData chart_pie = const IconData(0xe801, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
}
```

And I get my icon names from server as string

```
// dummy_data.dart
const SAY_SOME_DUMMY_DATA = const [
  MyModel(id: '1', icon: 'cash_register'),
  MyModel(id: '1', icon: 'chart_pie'),
];
```

My model looks like this:

```
class MyModel {
  final String id;
  final String icon;

  const MyModel({ this.id, this.icon });
}
```

My list builder looks like this:

```
Widget _listItemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
  const items = SAY_SOME_DUMMY_DATA;
  return ListItem(
    avatar: CircleAvatar(
      child: Icon(FaProLight.cash_register) // this work - no problem
      child: Icon(FaProLight.[items[index].icon]) // But, How to make this work?
    ),
  );
}
```

So, my question is:
How to make this work `FaProLight.[items[index].icon]` as mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access members using strings in Dart, however, you can simply convert your members to a map:

```dart
class FaProLight {
  FaProLight._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'FaProLight';

  static const Map<String, IconData> icons = {
    'cash_register': IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
    'chart_pie': IconData(0xe801, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
  };
}
```

Now, you can access it your icon like this:

```dart
CircleAvatar(
 child: Icon(FaProLight.icons[items[index].icon]),
)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, these are the times I miss Javascript the most :) Also, by converting it to `Map` I am will be missing nice code complete from my IDE(vs-code) :)

Comment: @Syed I feel you. For code completion, you could just keep the variables the way you had it before and then reference them in the map: `'chart_pie': chart_pie` So you can declare variables for the ones you want to access in code.

Comment: @Syed could you please explain your answer from the comments more?